# JavaScript shuffle array on submit and count up

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to shuffle an array on a submit from a `<input/>` in JavaScript then spit the `[0]` from the array into the div with the ID `message`. But when I press the submit button again. I want to get the `[1]` of the array. On the next submit the `[2]`. I want to continue this as long as the Array is. And than start over from `[0]`.

How I want it to work:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return submit()">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
<div id="message">
```

**JS:**

```
function submit() {
message = ["Message 1","Message 2","Message 3"] // I want more messages than this.
// The shuffle script here.
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message;
return false;
}
```

I have the array set up. But I want it to be shuffled and on a second submit spit out a other message so I don't have the same message twice.

The idea is just to get a random message from an array without getting the same message twice after a second submit.

If you have a bether idea of doing this please tell me.

Comment: You have to split this into two parts. 1) Generate and shuffle the array on page load (using the [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle), 2) Keep a counter and increment it on every submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to set a counter before your function and then inside your function set your message to the counters position in your array. Then when your counter reaches the length of the array reset the counter to 0. Something like this

```
var count = 0;
var message = ["Message 1","Message 2","Message 3"] // probably want this outside your submit function so its not declared everytime the function is called
function submit() {
  // The shuffle script here.
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message[count];
  if ((count + 1) >= message.length) {
    count = 0; // if the count + 1 is more than or equal to the array length then reset the counter
  } else {
    count += 1; // increase the count
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the way to do it! Thanks

Comment: What happens when the page refreshes? Wouldn't he lose the counter value?

Comment: I figured that the javascript submission of a form meant that this was an ajax submission so there would be no page refresh and the counter would stay. If not then I'll let @Finiox bring that up, perhaps your randomizing solution would be a good solution. A cookie could be set with the counter value, but that would be a bit more complex.

Comment: @Finiox look at the comment by Phylogenesis it's a better solution if you want to randomize the message.

Comment: @Phylogenesis only 1 problem when I paste this code into my project is gives me a error in the browsers console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Comment: Then `document.querySelector(...)` isn't returning anything. Have you changed the parameter to match your page?

Comment: @Finiox did you change the selector to "#submit" the ID of your input field? He has the selector set up to "button". You will also want to use Document.getElementById() instead of querySelector.

Comment: Changed it out. But thanks for the help I've the answer to my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Create a random number between 0 and 2. Use this number as an index to get the message from the array, like this:

```
function submit() {
    var message = ["Message 1","Message 2","Message 3"];
    var randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2));
    var myMessage = message[randomIndex];
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = myMessage;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: He mentioned not wanting to get the same message twice in a row. Maybe adding a check of what the last message was would be cool in your solution.

Comment: I would agree with you, however since he submits the page several times, the values of pop up messages would have to be saved in a hidden field. Perhaps he doesn't want this extra complexity. But I do agree this would be a nice improvement.

Comment: The solution of @LeoBauza works for me. Like Phylogesenis commented. I want to split this up. For the first part shuffle the array and for the second part get a counter.

Answer (score 0):

you can this function to shuffle an array.

```js
let yourArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
yourArray.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
console.log(yourArray);
```